# ¿Como asigno el permiso select a un rol en SQL SERVER (Me da error)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente actividad y mi codigo me marca error, ¿Alguien puede decirme que hice mal?

```
--8.-Asignar el permiso Select a este rol
    grant select on database Prueba to role 'GranSelectRole';
```

Me marca error en el "to" diciendo esto:
Incorrect syntax near to. Expecting DOUBLECOLON or ID.
¿Cual es la sintaxis correcta?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para poder asignar permisos a un rol, debes hacerlo mediante la siguiente instrucción use 'DATABASE'
grant select to [SQL User - Role]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata con :

```
 grant select on database Prueba to 'GranSelectRole';
```

No creo que sea necesario especificar "role"

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto, a mi me funcionó:

```
USE Prueba;
GRANT SELECT TO GranSelectRole;
```

¡Suerte!